# How do I mount as a read-write filesystem and not read-only?

Tags: linux, gentoo, chmod, chroot

I'm trying to install Gentoo in a virtual machine. I ran into this problem and began researching what the answer might be. The file system is read only. I can't mount it as read-write.

I'd rather start from the beginning and not make this mistake in the first place rather than fix it where it is. Could someone give me a clue as to how to make a read-only file system read-write when I can't write to it to make it read-write in the first place?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like you're trying to install gentoo using some shell script somewhere and copy-pasting didn't work?

First of all to remount a partition read write simply run `mount -o rw <devpath>` now with that out of the way this is probably not the issue, it appears you're trying to change files on the livecd instead of the chroot or mounted filesystem given the bash prompt which, of course, is a read-only filesystem.

Assuming you've actually created a suitable filesystem follow the guide from [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation#Installing_a_stage_tarball) (assuming amd64) and try again.

EDIT: Forget that it's virtual and your booting from a file imagine it as a regular desktop and you just inserted a disk containing the live system you're in.

Now when your machine boots it mounts the filesystem in memory and, at this point, to install you're supposed to setup your partitions on your hard drive and format them with suitable filesystems (ext3, swap, etc.), copy over the pertinent files/download any not included in the live cd via a package manager or similar methods (in this case a simple wget), and install a bootloader onto your hard drive (grub, lilo, etc.) to boot from.

It's not simple to the layman without a GUI that's why there's guides like this one to hold your hand through it.

Comment: You may have an answer if the essential parts from the link are posted here

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. Someone told me that since its a live cd (actually its an iso file in a vm that otherwise would be in a live cd), I have to actually install it onto the hard drive. But it feels like that would require me to copy the file system onto the hard drive which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a more detailed explanation, take a look and let me know if you have any questions.*